# What is the name for things like wigs, lashes and hair?

Tags: single-word-requests

We call these "cosmetics": skin moisturizers, perfumes, lipsticks, nail polish, eye and facial makeup, etc.

Then what's the term for things like wigs, lashes and hair?

Comment: Technically ... ***prosthetics***. But pragmatically speaking, that’s usually only applies to noses, legs, alien rubber makeup, etc.

Comment: Are you talking about _fake_ eyelashes and fake hair, rather than the eyelashes and hair that naturally grow on your body?

Comment: @DanBron Agree - but you'll never see a "Prosthetics" section next to the makeup aisle.  Perhaps **Accessories** may work?

Comment: @Balaz2ta Having recently been through a number of department stores' ground floors for Christmas (traditionally cosmetics and perfumes and accessories), I don't recall seeing anything like a special section for 'things made of or for hair' next to scarves and handbags. I'd expect these 'hair' things to be sold by ... hat makers? Hair dressers? What does amazon call them? I just looked them up: wigs and eyelashes under Beauty and Personal care'. This sounds so close to cosmetics, and I'm sure the local pharmacy has eyelashes in the cosmetics section.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes

Answer (score 1):

These things could be called

> **accoutrements** *n*
>   additional items of dress or equipment, or other items carried or worn by a person, or used for a particular activity
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/accoutrement)</sub>

For example, [accoutrements of fashion](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accoutrements+of+fashion&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccoutrements%20of%20fashion%3B%2Cc0) is attested.